# Why is silver chromate red?

Tags: aqueous-solution, ions, color

Copper(II) ions are blue and chromate(VI) ions are yellow therefore copper(II) chromate(VI) would turn out to be green because it's a mixture of blue and yellow.

In the same way, silver ions are colourless while chromate ions are yellow. So shouldn't silver chromate be yellow as well?

Comment: You can't just add colours like that. The ions interact with each other. Lead(II) and iodide ions are both colourless in solution but $\ce{PbI2}$ is yellow.

Comment: If so are there any ways to predict the colour of a compound?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/why-are-some-salt-solutions-coloured

Comment: You do not get green color by mixing a blue colored compound and a yellow colored compound. That's not how chemicals work.